# No mouse support for any boot cds on my new laptop

Tags: boot, mouse, iso-image

I use plenty of boot cds aspart of my work - such as macrium for imaging, and others for partition management and a variety of other multipurpose actions.  I recently bought a new laptop branded AVITA and when i booted u with the macrium boot cd, i found there was no mouse (trackpad) support WHICH IS THERE IN ALL MY OTHER LAPTOPS WHEN USING THE SAME BOOT CDS.  Yes i can plugin a usb mouse and it does work and provide me with a workaround for the issue.So what exactly is happening and why?  Is it a deficiency in the laptop BIOS?Is there a workaround (other than the above)? and can i introduce trackpad support by opening up the iso's themselves to introduce a trackpad driver for the same?Thanks for any help and enlightenment on this

Comment: Have you seen https://avita.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011411654-How-to-fix-Touch-pad-Issues

Comment: Thanks davidgo - that article and advice is for those working in the Window environment where  i am not facing any problem.  I am referring to no mouse support for bootCD s

Comment: Are these BootCD's Linux based?  If so, can you boot one up, open a terminal window, become root and provide the output of "lsusb", "xinput --list" and "cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -I touchpad"  The idea here is to try identify how Linux sees it so we can check/get the appropriate drivers to load.

Comment: See https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-touchpad-not-working-linux/

Comment: Davidgo: Can you guide me how to recognize a linux based cd and more advice and details on how to open a terminal window as i am not familiar with this at all but would like to solve this issue or at least understand it better?

Comment: By the way - when i say boot CDs i also include Bootable USBs

Comment: If you can't open a terminal window I don't think I can help you much. I can make statements about Linux based CDs but they will be meaningless to you.Did you want to tell me the names of the CD's - I may recognise them? (Also, for the purposed here, yes. USB bootable disk is equivalent to CD, and I posit most - but certainly not all - bootable disks are Linux based)

Comment: I can't help with Macrium. Never used it but it uses Windows PE.